# Is there a fast product operation for PackedArrays?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, numeric, packed

In Mathematica a vector (or rectangular array) containing all machine size integers or floats may be stored in a packed array.  These objects take less memory, and some operations are much faster on them.

`RandomReal` produces a packed array when possible.  A packed array can be unpacked with the `Developer` function `FromPackedArray`

Consider these timings

```
lst = RandomReal[1, 5000000];

Total[lst] // Timing
Plus @@ lst // Timing

lst = Developer`FromPackedArray[lst];

Total[lst] // Timing
Plus @@ lst // Timing

Out[1]= {0.016, 2.50056*10^6}

Out[2]= {0.859, 2.50056*10^6}

Out[3]= {0.625, 2.50056*10^6}

Out[4]= {0.64, 2.50056*10^6}
```

Therefore, in the case of a packed array, `Total` is many times faster than `Plus @@` but about the same for a non-packed array.  Note that `Plus @@` is actually a little slower on the packed array.

Now consider

```
lst = RandomReal[100, 5000000];
Times @@ lst // Timing

lst = Developer`FromPackedArray[lst];
Times @@ lst // Timing

Out[1]= {0.875, 5.8324791357*10^7828854}

Out[1]= {0.625, 5.8324791357*10^7828854}
```

Finally, my question: is there a fast method in Mathematica for the list product of a packed array, analogous to `Total`?

I suspect that this may not be possible because of the way that numerical errors compound with multiplication.  Also, the function will need to be able to return non-machine floats to be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've also wondered if there was a multiplicative equivalent to `Total`.

A <s>really</s> not so bad solution is

```
In[1]:= lst=RandomReal[2,5000000];
        Times@@lst//Timing
        Exp[Total[Log[lst]]]//Timing
Out[2]= {2.54,4.370467929041*10^-666614}
Out[3]= {0.47,4.370467940*10^-666614}
```

As long as the numbers are positive and aren't too big or small, 
then the rounding errors aren't too bad. 
A guess as to what might be happening during evaluation is that: (1) Provided the numbers are positive floats, the `Log` operation can be quickly applied to the packed array. (2) The numbers can then be quickly added using `Total`'s packed array method. (3) Then it's only the final step where a non-machine sized float need arise.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294640/is-there-a-fast-product-operation-for-packedarrays/5308395#5308395) for a solution that works for both positive and negative floats.

Let's quickly check that this solution works with floats that yield a non-machine sized answer. Compare with Andrew's (much faster) `compiledListProduct`:

```
In[10]:= compiledListProduct = 
          Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, 
           Module[{tot = 1.}, Do[tot *= x, {x, l}]; tot], 
           CompilationTarget -> "C"]

In[11]:= lst=RandomReal[{0.05,.10},15000000];
         Times@@lst//Timing
         Exp[Total[Log[lst]]]//Timing
         compiledListProduct[lst]//Timing
Out[12]= {7.49,2.49105025389*10^-16998863}
Out[13]= {0.5,2.4910349*10^-16998863}
Out[14]= {0.07,0.}
```

If you choose larger (`>1`) reals, then `compiledListProduct` will yield the warning
`CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.` and will take some time to give a result...

---

One curio is that both `Sum` and `Product` can take arbitrary lists. `Sum` works fine

```
In[4]:= lst=RandomReal[2,5000000];
         Sum[i,{i,lst}]//Timing
         Total[lst]//Timing
Out[5]= {0.58,5.00039*10^6}
Out[6]= {0.02,5.00039*10^6}
```

but for long `PackedArray`s, such as the test examples here, `Product` fails since the automatically compiled code (in version 8.0) does not catch underflows/overflows properly:

```
In[7]:= lst=RandomReal[2,5000000];
         Product[i,{i,lst}]//Timing
         Times@@lst//Timing
Out[8]= {0.,Compile`AutoVar12!}
Out[9]= {2.52,1.781498881673*10^-666005}
```

The work around supplied by the helpful WRI tech support is to turn off the product compilation using `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"ProductCompileLength" -> Infinity}]`. Another option is to use `` lst=Developer`FromPackedArray[lst] ``.

Comment: Your "really bad solution" may not have good precision, but it **is** much faster, and really may be the best that is possible given the nature of multiplication.  If nothing better is posted, this gets my checkmark. +1  Also, on my system (Win32, Mma7) it is about 40X faster than `Times @@` on your example.

Comment: Good idea. The `Log` lets you keep almost all the calculations in machine precision.

Comment: @Andrew: If only I could claim that was the reason I used `Log`... When I supplied the answer my original motivation was just to turn the product into a sum, I hadn't even thought about machine vs arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: ProdTotal[ ] is scheduled to appear in version 8.π

Comment: @belisarius 8.π ?  If that is mathematician's humor, it's over my head.

Comment: @Mr. Ohh well, my sense of humor is asymptotically approaching idiocy as years go by.

Comment: @belisarius, no, _that_ was funny. :-D

Comment: +1, turning multiplication into addition. simple and effective.

Comment: By the way, Product[i, {i,lst}] does not fail for me, it is merely slow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: What values did you use? My Mma-V8 only fails for large lists that yield a non-machine valued result... My Mma-V7 install works fine. Eg compare `Product[i, {i, RandomReal[1, 50000]}]` with `Product[i, {i, RandomReal[{.99, 1.01}, 50000]}]` and `Product[i, {i, RandomReal[10, 50000]}]` - only the middle one works for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: OK, I've submitted a bug report. WRI can sort out what's going on!

Answer (score 4):

First, to avoid confusion, take a look at an example whose results are all representable as hardware machine precision numbers, which must all be less than

```
In[1]:= $MaxMachineNumber

Out[1]= 1.79769*10^308
```

Your Total example already had this nice (and fast) property. Here is a variant on your Times example using machine numbers:

```
In[2]:= lst = RandomReal[{0.99, 1.01}, 5000000];
Times @@ lst // Timing

Out[3]= {1.435, 1.38851*10^-38}
```

Now we can use [Compile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) to make a compiled function to perform this operation efficiently:

```
In[4]:= listproduct = 
 Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{tot = 1.}, Do[tot *= x, {x, l}]; tot]]

Out[4]= CompiledFunction[{l},Module[{tot=1.},Do[tot*=x,{x,l}];tot],-CompiledCode-]
```

It's much faster:

```
In[5]:= listproduct[lst] // Timing

Out[5]= {0.141, 1.38851*10^-38}
```

Assuming you have a C compiler and Mathematica 8, you can also automatically compile all the way to C code. A temporary DLL is created and linked back into Mathematica at run-time.

```
In[6]:= compiledlistproduct = 
 Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{tot = 1.}, Do[tot *= x, {x, l}]; tot], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]

Out[6]= CompiledFunction[{l},Module[{tot=1.},Do[tot*=x,{x,l}];tot],-CompiledCode-]
```

This gives performance not much different to that which a built-in Mathematica function would have:

```
In[7]:= compiledlistproduct[lst] // Timing

Out[7]= {0.015, 1.38851*10^-38}
```

Note that if your product really will go beyond $[MaxMachineNumber](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MaxMachineNumber.html) (or [$MinMachineNumber](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MinMachineNumber.html)), then you are better off sticking with `Apply[Times, list]`. The same comment applies to Total, if your results can get that big:

```
In[11]:= lst = RandomReal[10^305, 5000000];
Plus @@ lst // Timing

Out[12]= {1.435, 2.499873364498981*10^311}

In[13]:= lst = RandomReal[10^305, 5000000];
Total[lst] // Timing

Out[14]= {1.576, 2.500061580905602*10^311}
```

Comment: Andrew, not to sound ungrateful, but I was already aware of Compile, which is why I stated: "the function will need to be able to return non-machine floats to be useful."  Is a faster function than `Times @@` in my original example possible, or is that just the nature of the numbers?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I missed that detail. Nothing simple jumps to mind so far that will be better than `Times @@`, and the same problem applies to Total (although you may rarely get the numbers so large there).

Comment: This is still a fine answer for anyone reading this question.

Comment: +1, for all you guys at Wolfram for the new feature of compiling to machine code and linking back in via a temp dll.  Just need to get v. 8 now ... As an aside, can the DLL be saved, i.e. could I compile a package, save the dll, and reuse it later?

Comment: Yes, you would create a DLL with LibraryGenerate (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/ref/LibraryGenerate.html), and load it again with http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html. Note that, just as with Compile, it is generally only the "C-like" pieces of Mathematica that will compile to fast code.

Answer (score 3):

Simon's method is fast, but it fails on negative values.  Combining it with [his answer to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306252/fast-list-product-sign-for-packedarray/5307685#5307685), here is a fast solution that handles negatives.  Thanks, Simon.

### Function

```
f = (-1)^(-1 /. Rule @@@ Tally@Sign@# /. -1 -> 0) * Exp@Total@Log@Abs@# &;
```

---

### Testing

```
lst = RandomReal[{-50, 50}, 5000000];

Times @@ lst // Timing
f@lst // Timing

lst = Developer`FromPackedArray[lst];

Times @@ lst // Timing
f@lst // Timing
```

---

```
{0.844, -4.42943661963*10^6323240}

{0.062, -4.4294366*10^6323240}

{0.64, -4.42943661963*10^6323240}

{0.203, -4.4294366*10^6323240}
```